# Invalid Response - JSON & Laravel 5. 6

Tags: laravel

In my code below is a json response that i am trying to access its element. When i get the description from the response, i get an error. Below is the structure of the response

How do i get the description from the response ? I am only able to get `success` by `$response->success`

**Response**

```
{"description":["My Description Is Here"],"success":true}
```

When i validate the json, it is actually a valid json.  What could i be doing wrong ?

**Code**

```
$response = {"description":["My Description Is Here"],"success":true}  
if ($response->state == true) {
$message = $response->detail;
} else {
     //do something here
 }
```

Comment: Your PHP Code should throw you syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to work with JSON in PHP. But at first you have to decode it into object:

```
$response = json_decode('{"description":["My Description Is Here"],"success":true}');
```